# Chrome input autosuggest remembered value change CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, autocomplete

When Chrome remembers user/pass fields and automatically suggests that entry to the user, I can't seem to change the CSS of those input fields.

You can try for example editing Facebook password field in login form through DevTools in Chrome:

```
element.style {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

You will see that password field doesn't turn green.

Firefox works great, this seems to be the issue only with Chrome.

So basic question is:
**How to override browser's built-in CSS for autosuggest / autocomplete field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the autocomplete feature for the browser.

```
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Or you can use this for customizing in chrome:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
border: 1px solid green;
-webkit-text-fill-color: green;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! (I mean, CSS part, I didn't want to kill autocomplete)

Comment: Okay sounds good. Yeah i gave both solution if you want to control the autocomplete attr also.